# Loading is not showing in react hooks

Tags: reactjs

Below is the error in my browser console.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. 
See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information. 
ExpenseList@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1481:7 div 
Card@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2299:19 div 
Expenses@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:975:97 div 
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:252:89 index.js:1
```

I get this error even before I input any new expense. I have gone to the expenses list class and I cannot seem to find the issuse. Below is the ExpensesList class

```
import React from "react";
 
import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem";
import './ExpensesList.css';
 
const ExpenseList = props => {
 
    if (props.expenses.length > 0) {
      
      return props.expenses.map((expense) => (
        <ul className="expenses-list">
          <ExpenseItem
            key={expense.id}
            title={expense.title}
            amount={expense.amount}
            date={expense.date}
          />
        </ul>
      ));
    }
 
    return <h2 className="expenses-list__fallback">Found No Expenses</h2>;
 
 
}
 
export default ExpenseList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Your error is related to the map that you are using in your code to render the list of expenses.

In React you must specify a `key` props whenever you render a list in order to help React render the list correctly:

```js
return (
  <ul className="expenses-list">
    {props.expenses.map((expense) => (
      <ExpenseItem
        key={expense.id}
        title={expense.title}
        amount={expense.amount}
        date={expense.date}
      />
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

For more information on keys and lists you can read the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Edited with correct structure, thanks to [Sobhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16390814/sobhan-jahanmard) for the comment.

Comment: You should probably let him know that he needs to move out the ```ul``` from inside of the map function as he is returning a ```ul``` with each occurrence of the map.